# how to show animated loading gif when the button is clicked vb.net using backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, backgroundworker

everyone, **I updated my question**, I am just a newbie in Visual Basic.Net and Oracle stored procedure.

I have this set of codes where I found on the internet. It works but, how can I convert this importing CSV file from fetching rows from the database using Oracle stored procedure.

```
    Dim strRow As String()              'String array to read all fields in a row
Dim dblAmount As Double             'Variable for total amount 
Dim blnReported As Boolean = True   'Flag to check progress report completed or not

'Create TextFieldParser class to parse the stock.csv file in the current location
Dim txtFile As FileIO.TextFieldParser

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Allow background operation to be cancelled
    bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

    'Allow background operation to report progress
    bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True

    'Disable Stop Button. It is enabled only after start
    'button is pressed
    btnStop.Enabled = False

    'set status message
    lblStatus.Text = "Press Start to import data from csv."

    'Add columns to the grid
    dgvCSVData.Columns.Add("colNo", "No")
    dgvCSVData.Columns("colNo").Width = 30
    dgvCSVData.Columns.Add("colDate", "Date")
    dgvCSVData.Columns("colDate").Width = 60
    dgvCSVData.Columns.Add("colItem", "Item")
    dgvCSVData.Columns("colItem").Width = 120
    dgvCSVData.Columns.Add("colQty", "Quantity")
    dgvCSVData.Columns("colQty").Width = 50
    dgvCSVData.Columns.Add("colUnit", "Unit")
    dgvCSVData.Columns("colUnit").Width = 30
    dgvCSVData.Columns.Add("colAmt", "Amt")
    dgvCSVData.Columns("colAmt").Width = 60
End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    'Disable Start button and Enable Stop
    btnStart.Enabled = False
    btnStop.Enabled = True

    'set status message
    lblStatus.Text = "Importing data from CSV file."

    'Start time-consuming operation in background
    Call bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    'Enable Start button and disable Stop
    btnStart.Enabled = True
    btnStop.Enabled = False

    'Stop background operation
    bgWorker.CancelAsync()

    'set status message
    lblStatus.Text = "Import cancelled. Press Start again."
End Sub

Private Sub bgWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.DoWork
    Dim intCount As Int16 = 0
    txtFile = New FileIO.TextFieldParser("stock.csv")
    'Specify structure of the file
    txtFile.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    txtFile.SetDelimiters(",")

    'Skip header row
    txtFile.ReadFields()

    'Start reading data from file
    While Not txtFile.EndOfData

        If bgWorker.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub

        Else

            'Wait for Progress Report to finish
            While Not blnReported
                Application.DoEvents()
            End While

            'Read all field in a row into a string array
            strRow = txtFile.ReadFields()

            'Do some calculations and assign value to data grid
            dblAmount = CDbl(strRow(3)) * CDbl(strRow(4))

            'Add some sleep to simulate a long running operation
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)

            'Progress report pending
            blnReported = False

            'increment counter
            intCount += 1

            'Report the progress
            bgWorker.ReportProgress(10, intCount)

        End If

    End While
End Sub

Private Sub bgWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.ProgressChanged
    'Copy values to data grid
    dgvCSVData.Rows.Add(strRow)
    dgvCSVData.Rows(dgvCSVData.CurrentRow.Index - 1).Cells("colAmt").Value = dblAmount

    pgbCopyProgress.Value = e.UserState
    'Progress report finished
    blnReported = True
End Sub

Private Sub bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled Or Not IsNothing(e.Error) Then
        'Clear the data grid
        dgvCSVData.Rows.Clear()
    Else
        'Progress completed
        pgbCopyProgress.Value = 100

        'Release txtfile
        txtFile.Dispose()
        btnStop.Enabled = False
        btnStart.Enabled = True

    End If
End Sub
```

**Here's my code in calling the rows in the database**

```
 Public Function RESA_Checker(ByVal stores As String, ByVal bus_date As String, ByVal warehouse As String)
    dt = New DataTable
    bg.GetProcDataTable(connStr, "SALES_CHECKER.procedure_checker")
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("stores", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = stores
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("bus_date", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = bus_date
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("warehouse", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = warehouse
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("O_OUTPUT", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    adap_or.SelectCommand = cmd
    adap_or.Fill(dt)


    Return dt
    ora_conn.Close()
End Function
```

My purpose is that the user will be informed through a dialog box with progress bar or animated gif, that the form is loading and still fetching records from the database says "Please wait"/"Searching", and prevent confusion to the user, of having thought that the form is crashed.

P.s. It would be helpful if give the links of the video tutorials. 
I do hope you could help me , Thanks.

Comment: A GIF is an image. You display an `Image` in a `PictureBox`. You don't need a video tutorial for that. Apart from that, this is a Q&A site. It's not a place that you ask for us to point you to places to learn how to program. You need to do your research, make an attempt to implement what you have learned and then, if you encounter an ACTUAL issue, THEN you post all the information relevant to that.

Comment: See: [ImageAnimator class (MSDN docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageanimator?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @Jimi and your assumption is that the user is targeting >= 4.5 framework? What about frameworks < 4.5 as the user could be using older framework?

Comment: @Codexer  He didn't specify a target Framework. I have to assume for the OP it's irrelevant. If it's not, the OP will have to update the questions, adding the necessary specifications. 4.5 is quite old anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Note: You've changed your question (you should've created a new Question instead of changing your old one) and I'm not familiar with Oracle, so this information may now be irrelevant.

Like you, I'm a noobie too, but we can figure this out. There's many ways to do this, so I'll list a few. If none scratch your itch, hopefully they will have pointed you in the right direction. I also see you know what backgroundworker is, so I'll assume you know how it works or can find the resources to figure it out yourself (if not I'll link some resources to it below).

**ProgressBar:**

You can increment a progressbar throughout your button's process to indicate that the process is not over.

Below, when the button is pressed it searches a list for the string "Snow White". If the current string it's checking within the list is not "Snow White" the ProgressBar1 increments to show that a move title has been checked. This will loop until the "Snow White" string comes around. Then our loop will display a completed ProgressBar1 and display "Found it!"

*Example Code:*

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim moviesList As New List(Of String) From {"Cinderella", "Snow White", "Rapunzel"}
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = moviesList.Count()
    For Each movie In moviesList
        If movie = "Snow White" Then
            ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum
            Label1.Text = "Found it!"
        Else
            ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Label:**

You can display a label telling the user that the button's process is still processing until it finishes.

Below, when the button is pressed it searches a list for the string "Snow White" and sets Label1 to "Loading...". If the current string it's checking within the list is not "Snow White" it continues like normal, if it is "Snow White" it will update Label1 to say "Found it!". By displaying this the user can see whether the program is loading or not.

*Example Code:*

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim moviesList As New List(Of String) From {"Cinderella", "Snow White", "Rapunzel"}
    Label1.Text = "Loading..."
    For Each movie In moviesList
        If movie = "Snow White" Then
            Label1.Text = "Found it!"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Animated Gif:**

You can display an animated gif while the button's process processes.

Below, when the button is pressed it searches a list for the string "Snow White" and sets PictureBox1's Visible property to True. If you have added a gif to PictureBox1 (if you don't know how I linked it in resources) you can see the PictureBox1's loading gif. When the loop finds the "Snow White" string within the moviesList it will display "Found it!" in Label1 and set PictureBox1's Visible property to False.

*Example Code:*

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim moviesList As New List(Of String) From {"Cinderella", "Snow White", "Rapunzel"}
    PictureBox1.Visible = True
    For Each movie In moviesList
        If movie = "Snow White" Then
            PictureBox1.Visible = False
            Label1.Text = "Found it!"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Resources:**

For additional information you can use these to achieve what you want.

Animate a PictureBox:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zsvi0p9YUE4

Put a Gif in a PictureBox:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igSsB_61BR8

Create a loading screen:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8mtv9zJBD0

BackgroundWorker Information:
[BackgroundWorker Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response on my first quesiton, it helps but, I can't create a new question right now, so I have no choice to edit this.

Comment: It is okay, if you didn't know oracle. But do know how to connect your answer to database, instead of declaring it.

Comment: No idea how it works, I'm having a similar issue currently. If you figure it out let me know.